# Simplify array of objects with children using JQ

Tags: jq, sparql, wikidata

From Wikidata, I get the following json:

```bash
# Sparql query
query=$(cat ./myquery.sparql)
response=$(curl -G --data-urlencode query="${query}" https://wikidata.org/sparql?format=json)
echo "${response}" | jq '.results.bindings'
```

```js
[
  {
    "language": {
      "type": "uri",
      "value": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q100"
    },
    "wikidata": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "Q36157"
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "lub"
    }
  },
  {
    "language": {
      "type": "uri",
      "value": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q101"
    },
    "wikidata": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "Q36284"
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "srr"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to have the keys directly paired with their values, such as :

```
[
  {
    "language": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q100",
    "wikidata": "Q36157",
    "iso": "lub"
  },
  {
    "language": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q101",
    "wikidata": "Q36284",
    "iso": "srr"
  }
]
```

I currently have a non-resilient code, which will break whenever the key names change :

```bash
jq 'map({"language":.language.value,"wikidata":.wikidata.value,"iso":.code.value})'
```

**How to pair the keys with their values in a resilient way (not naming the keys) ?**
I want to "prune" the child objects so to only keep the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map_values` which works like the outer `map` but for objects, i.e. it retains the object structure, including the field names:

```bash
jq 'map(map_values(.value))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "language": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q100",
    "wikidata": "Q36157",
    "code": "lub"
  },
  {
    "language": "https://lingualibre.org/entity/Q101",
    "wikidata": "Q36284",
    "code": "srr"
  }
]
```

Note that this solution lacks the name conversion from `code` to `iso`.

Comment: Seems great. I can deal with occasional name changes via other treatments.